# Extract image from PowerPoint and add to Word Using VSTO add-in c#

Tags: c#, vsto, powerpoint

Let me explain what i am trying to achieve using VSTO add-ins C#

There are two part of this question

Part 1: I am trying to get all PowerPoint slides text and images

I am able to get the text but unable to fetch the images from PowerPoint slide

```
var allslides = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActivePresentation.Slides;

                foreach (PowerPoint.Slide sld in allslides)
                {
                    foreach (PowerPoint.Shape shape in sld.Shapes)
                    {
                        if (shape.TextFrame.HasText != 0)
                        {
                                var textRange = shape.TextFrame.TextRange;
                                Word.Paragraph para1 = document.Content.Paragraphs.Add(ref missing);
                                object styleHeading1 = "Normal";
                                para1.Range.set_Style(ref styleHeading1);
                                para1.Range.Font.Size = 14;
                                para1.Range.ListFormat.ApplyBulletDefault();
                                string[] bulletItems = textRange.Text.Split('\r');

                                for (int i = 0; i < bulletItems.Length; i++)
                                {
                                    string bulletItem = bulletItems[i];
                                    if (i < bulletItems.Length - 1)
                                        bulletItem = bulletItem + "\n";
                                    para1.Range.InsertBefore(bulletItem);
                                }
                                para1.Range.InsertParagraphAfter();
                            }
                        else
                        {                            
                            //Console.WriteLine("Image File here");
                        }
                    }
        }
```

Part 2: I am creating word file dynamically

Then inserting text and images fetch from PowerPoint to word

So i need help also to insert fetch image to word document

Creating Word document dynamically using below code

```
Word.Application winword = new Word.Application(); 
                winword.ShowAnimation = false;

                winword.Visible = false;

                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

                //Create a new document  
                Word.Document document = winword.Documents.Add(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                document.Content.SetRange(0, 0);
```

Comment: That's quite a bit of code, can you condense it down to create a simple example/question and to show which part of code is causing problems.

Comment: @RichardHousham i have modified the code